# How to sort the values ​contained in JSON within the Array?

Tags: php, json

I am receiving data from the database, this data is coming in Array with JSON contained. I would like to group the repeated values ​​by header, ie GROUP being the title, BREED being the header and NAME being the description of this header as shown below.

> **Vehicles (GROUP)**
>
> **Electric (BREED)**
>
> Audi A3 Sportback
>
> BMW i3
>
> Chevrolet Bolt
>
> Chrysler Pacifica PHEV
>
> Ford Fusion Energi
>
> Hyundai IONIQ Electric
>
> Mercedes GLE 550
>
> Ford F
>
> Mitsubishi/Nissan
>
> **Self-Propelled (BREED)**
>
> Infantry Fighting
>
> Armored reconnaissance
>
> Cavalry Fighting
>
> Armored personnel
>
> aerial tramway
>
> baby carriage
>
> delivery truck
>
> Nissan LEAF
>
> Earth mover

Here is the Array with JSON inside, below is the loop to get the information.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    '{
    "GROUP": "Vehicle",
    "BREED": "Self-Propelled",
    "NAME": "Infantry fighting."
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Electric",
        "NAME": "Audi A3 Sportback."
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Self-Propelled",
        "NAME": "Armored reconnaissance"
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Electric",
        "NAME": "BMW i3"
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Self-Propelled",
        "NAME": "Cavalry fighting"
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Electric",
        "NAME": "Chevrolet Bolt"
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Electric",
        "NAME": "Chrysler Pacifica PHEV."
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Self-Propelled",
        "NAME": "Armored personnel"
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Electric",
        "NAME": "Ford Fusion Energi."
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Self-Propelled",
        "NAME": "aerial tramway"
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Self-Propelled",
        "NAME": "baby carriage"
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Electric",
        "NAME": "Hyundai IONIQ Electric."
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Self-Propelled",
        "NAME": "delivery truck"
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Electric",
        "NAME": "Mercedes GLE 550e."
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Electric",
        "NAME": "Ford F"
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Self-Propelled",
        "NAME": "Nissan LEAF."
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Self-Propelled",
        "NAME": "Earth mover"
    }',
    '{
        "GROUP": "Vehicle",
        "BREED": "Electric",
        "NAME": "Mitsubishi/Nissan"
    }'

);


    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){  
        $obj = json_decode($array[$i]);

        echo '<p><h1>'.$obj->GROUP.'</h1> <b>'.$obj->BREED.'</b> - '.$obj->NAME.'</p>';
    }

?>
```

Note that BREED and GROUP repeat over and over, how can I make them look like the top model?

Comment: Hey Sergio, have you tried something in PHP? The idea at Stackoverflow is that you share your code, however imperfect, so we can have a look at it and come up with possible suggestions for improvement.

Comment: Hello, I put the PHP code, the output I want, is via 'echo', if you scroll down the code I posted, you will see the loop for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the post again I realized, that there *is* an attempt in there already (sorry for my earlier comment saying otherwise ...). Here is my suggestion on how to solve the problem of restructuring the data:

```
$newarr=array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){  
  $obj = json_decode($array[$i]);
  $newarr[$obj->GROUP][$obj->BREED][]=$obj->NAME;
}
foreach ($newarr as $group => $breeds) {
    echo "<h1>$group</h1>\n";    
    foreach ($breeds as $breed => $vehicles) 
      echo "<p><b>$breed</b><br>\n".join("<br>\n",$vehicles)."</p>\n";
}
```

You can find a working demo here: https://rextester.com/OYD48391

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure your data first then render them, something like the following

```
// we will restructure the array to look like the following
[
    "Vehicle" => [
        "Self-Propelled" => [
            0 => "Infantry fighting.",
            1 => "Cavalry fighting",
            2 => "Armored personnel",
            3 => "aerial tramway",
            4 => "baby carriage",
            5 => "delivery truck",
            6 => "Nissan LEAF.",
            7 => "Earth mover",
        ],        
        "Electric" => [
            0 => "Audi A3 Sportback.",
            1 => "BMW i3",
            2 => "Chevrolet Bolt",
            3 => "Chrysler Pacifica PHEV.",
            4 => "Ford Fusion Energi.",
            5 => "Hyundai IONIQ Electric.",
            6 => "Mercedes GLE 550e.",
            7 => "Ford F",
            8 => "Mitsubishi/Nissan",
        ]
    ],
    "Passageiro" => [
        "Self-Propelled" => [
            0 => "Armored reconnaissance",
        ]
    ],
]
```

```
// first restructure the array
$restructuredArray = [];
foreach ($array as $jsonData) {
    $data = json_decode($jsonData);
    $restructuredArray[$data->GROUP] = $restructuredArray[$data->GROUP] ?? [];
    $restructuredArray[$data->GROUP][$data->BREED] = $restructuredArray[$data->GROUP][$data->BREED] ?? [];
    $restructuredArray[$data->GROUP][$data->BREED][] = $data->NAME;
}
// second rendering the restructured array
foreach ($restructuredArray as $group => $breeds) {
    echo "<h1>{$group}</h1>";
    foreach($breeds as $breed => $names) {
        echo "<h3>{$breed}</h3>";
        foreach($names as $name) {
            echo "<p>{$name}</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

**Advice**
If you have control over the database it will be better to save the data in a better format or structure and in your case you can use either SQL (Like MySQL using relations) or NoSQL (Document based database like MongoDB) and both will fit for your need.